# Oracle SQL Find Sequential Values Based on Criteria in Another Column

Tags: oracle

I am doing a project to find a list of paired left right parts in a table. The table contains a column of Unique Part IDs and a column of Left or Right attributes.

If there is a right left pair in the table then the left ID will appear one Unique Part ID before the Right (ID 4 will be Left and ID 5 will be Right). However, there are many Unique IDs between each Left Right Pair that do not have a pair. I'm trying to write a query to find all Left and Right pairs within the table.

For example (currently Both ID and LR are VARCHAR2)

```
ID  LR
1   L
2   R
5   R
9   R
22  R
34  L
35  R
38  L
91  L
92  R
```

and I need the query to return

```
ID  LR
1   L
2   R
34  L
35  R
91  L
92  R
```

My current line of thinking is a conditional query to select all IDs and LR when LR is R the ID - 1 exists and that LR is L but I'm not sure...any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set operations is one way you could do this.

(edited to rewrite query as per comments - it now handles leading zeros in the varchar ID field)

---

```
WITH matches AS (
    SELECT to_number(ID) AS ID_integer
    FROM base_table
    WHERE LR = 'L'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT to_number(ID)-1
    FROM base_table
    WHERE LR = 'R'
)
SELECT bt.ID, bt.LR, m.ID_integer
FROM base_table bt, matches m
WHERE LR = 'L'
AND to_number(bt.ID) = m.ID_integer
UNION
SELECT bt.ID, bt.LR, m.ID_integer
FROM base_table bt, matches m
WHERE LR = 'R'
AND to_number(bt.ID)-1 = m.ID_integer
ORDER BY 3, 2;
```

Comment: This won't work - did you notice that the ID's are not a consecutive sequence? The next ID after 2 is 5, not 3.

Comment: @mathguy, I just tested it and it's working as it should.

Comment: Change the id 2 so it is 3 instead of 2 (with lr = R) and keep everything else the same, see if the query still works.

Comment: @mathguy I think this is a difference in the way we read and interpret the question. As I understand it, 1 L and 3 R is not intended to be a match.

Comment: Thank you both immensely for your help! Peter M. is correct in saying that 1 L and 3 R is not intended to be a match. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I could have better emphasized that need.

Comment: @PeterM. Your query works great except, I know I did not mention this in the question but ID also contains IDs with preceding 0 (such as 001, 002, etc.). I found your code works for all IDs except for those with preceding 0 (for IDs with preceding 0, the query returns all LR = 'R'). Do you know if there is anything I can do to use your query to sort the IDs with preceding 0s? Thank you immensely again for your help.

Comment: @mlin, sure thing. I've edited the answer to handle that.

Comment: @PeterM. This worked! Thank you so much...you're the best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with inputs ( id, lr ) as (
       select  1, 'L' from dual union all
       select  2, 'R' from dual union all
       select  5, 'R' from dual union all
       select  9, 'R' from dual union all
       select 22, 'R' from dual union all
       select 34, 'L' from dual union all
       select 35, 'R' from dual union all
       select 38, 'L' from dual union all
       select 91, 'L' from dual union all
       select 92, 'R' from dual
     ),
     prep ( id, lr, prev_lr, next_lr ) as (
       select id, lr, lag(lr) over (order by id), lead(lr) over (order by id)
       from   inputs
     )
select   id, lr
from     prep
where    (lr = 'L' and next_lr = 'R') or (lr = 'R' and prev_lr = 'L')
order by id
;


        ID L
---------- -
         1 L
         2 R
        34 L
        35 R
        91 L
        92 R
```