# Oracle SQL Pair Right Left Sequential Numbers with Identifiers

Tags: oracle

I am trying to pair left right parts in a table. The table contains columns Unique Part IDs, Identifiers, and Left/Right Indicator. I received an answer for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440395/oracle-sql-find-sequential-values-based-on-criteria-in-another-column) assuming the left part always come before the right but I have found that this is not the case.

Currently the only way to identify a pair is if they have the same identifier and the matching part is one part before or one part after, if a right hand part has the same identifier as the left hand subsequent part then that is the correct pair but if the left hand part has the same identifier as the right subsequent part then that is the correct pair. For example (Currently ID, Identifier, are VARCHAR2)

(ID 4 will be Left and ID 5 will be Right). However, there are many Unique IDs between each Left Right Pair that do not have a pair. I'm trying to write a query to find all Left and Right pairs within the table.

For example (currently Both ID and LR are VARCHAR2)

```
ID  LR  Identifier
1   L   B15A
2   R   A15C
3   L   A15C
4   R   A15C
5   L   A15C
6   R   D5A2
9   R   D5A2
10  L   E5A6 
11  R   E5A6
12  L   E5A6
13  R   E5A6
14  R   H9S5
17  L   EE5A
18  R   EE5A
```

and I need the query to return

```
ID  LR  Identifier
2   R   A15C
3   L   A15C
4   R   A15C
5   L   A15C
10  L   E5A6 
11  R   E5A6
12  L   E5A6
13  R   E5A6
17  L   EE5A
18  R   EE5A
```

The link to the previous question is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440395/oracle-sql-find-sequential-values-based-on-criteria-in-another-column). The problem is if I search by Left before Right (or vice versa) I will incorrectly match pairs. Therefore the query must find the first identifier in the chain and then pair the subsequent part if it exists regardless of if it is a right or left hand For example an incorrect example is:

```
ID  LR  Identifier
3   L   A15C
4   R   A15C
10  L   E5A6 
11  R   E5A6
12  L   E5A6
13  R   E5A6
17  L   EE5A
18  R   EE5A
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Also, let's make sure the requirement is clear enough. Are you saying that IF a pair is found, the two rows WILL be right next to each other? Or could the pair of an identifier be several rows later, not in the immediately following row?

Comment: @mathguy Yes your first statement is correct. If a pair is found the part with the same identifier will either be one part number after or one part number before. I am also using Oracle 12.9.0.71

(p.s. thanks for all your previous help!! this is just...a never ending project)

Comment: Oracle only goes up to 12.1 right now (I believe there may have been a limited release of 12.2 recently). `select * from v$version` will give you the answer.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I put in my Toad version instead. I am at 11.2.0.4.0 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works more generally, even if the pairs are not necessarily found right next to each other. (If that is in fact REQUIRED, if parts cannot be paired if their ID's are not consecutive, that condition can be added to the query.)

```
with
     test_data ( id, lr, identifier ) as (
       select '001', 'L', 'B15A' from dual union all
       select '002', 'R', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select '003', 'L', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select '004', 'R', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select '005', 'L', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select '006', 'R', 'D5A2' from dual union all
       select '009', 'R', 'D5A2' from dual union all
       select '010', 'L', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select '011', 'R', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select '012', 'L', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select '013', 'R', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select '014', 'R', 'H9S5' from dual union all
       select '017', 'L', 'EE5A' from dual union all
       select '018', 'R', 'EE5A' from dual
     )
-- end of test data, the solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select id, lr, identifier
from ( select id, lr, identifier,
              row_number() over (partition by identifier, lr order by id) as rn,
              least( count(case when lr = 'L' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier),
                     count(case when lr = 'R' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier)
                   ) as least_count
       from   test_data
)
where rn <= least_count
order by id               --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID  LR IDENTIFIER
--- -- ----------
002 R  A15C
003 L  A15C
004 R  A15C
005 L  A15C
010 L  E5A6
011 R  E5A6
012 L  E5A6
013 R  E5A6
017 L  EE5A
018 R  EE5A

 10 rows selected
```

Explanation: In the inner query, I add two more columns to the initial data. One, `rn`, counts separately (starting from 1 and incrementing by 1) for each identifier, separately for 'L' and for 'R'. This will be used to form the pairs. And, `ct` gives the least of the total counts for 'L' and 'R' for each identifier. In the outer query, I just filter out all rows where `rn > ct` - those are the rows without a pair in the initial table. What's left are the pairs.

**ADDED**:  With the additional condition that a pair must be formed from "consecutive" rows (as measured by the `id` column), this becomes a more interesting question. It's a gaps-and-islands problem (identify groups of consecutive rows with the same characteristic), but with a twist: the `LR` value must be alternating within the group, rather than constant. The very efficient "tabibitosan" method can't be applied here (I think); the "start of group" method, which is more general, does work. This is what I used here. Note that in the end I leave out the very last row in a group, if the count for the group is an odd number. (We may find two, or four, or six consecutive rows that form one or two or three pairs, but not an odd number of rows with alternating LR). Note also that if two rows have the same identifier AND LR, the second row will always start a NEW group, so if it is in fact part of a pair (with the row AFTER it), that will be caught correctly by this solution.

Compare this to the MATCH_RECOGNIZE solution for Oracle 12 and above I posted separately - and appreciate how much simpler it is!

```
with
     prep ( id, lr, identifier, flag ) as (
       select id, lr, identifier,
              case when identifier = lag(identifier) over (order by id) 
                    and lr        != lag(lr)         over (order by id)
                   then null else 1 end
       from test_data    --  replace "test_data" with actual table name
     ), 
     with_groups ( id, lr, identifier, gp ) as (
       select id, lr, identifier,
              sum(flag) over (order by id)
       from   prep
     ),
     with_rn ( id, lr, identifier, rn, ct ) as (
       select id, lr, identifier,
              row_number() over (partition by identifier, gp order by id),
              count(*)     over (partition by identifier, gp)
       from   with_groups
     )
select   id, lr, identifier
from     with_rn
where    rn < ct or mod(rn, 2) = 0
order by id               --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! For this project there can be the same identifier for non consecutive parts but not be a correctly paired part. Could you add the condition where ID's must be consecutive? Thanks again.

Comment: @mlin - OK. What should happen if you have three consecutive rows with the same IDENTIFIER, with L, then R, then L?  Just show the first two, and only show the last one if it is paired with a fourth row with the same IDENTIFIER and with LR = R? I assume so, but would like to know for sure.

Comment: Yes you are correct. If there is three consecutive rows with the same IDENTIFIER that is L, R, L  (or R, L, R) then only show the first two.

Comment: @mlin - OK, added to the answer. It was a bit more complicated than I expected - good practice problem!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is an answer that uses the Oracle 12.1 and above MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause. (It will not help the OP at this time, he is on 11.2, but it may help others in the future.) It assumes the additional condition that a pair can only be formed if the rows forming the pair are consecutive in the original table.

```
select id, lr, identifier
from test_data   --  replace "test_data" with the actual table name
match_recognize (
  order by id
  all rows per match
  pattern ( A B )
  define B as B.identifier = A.identifier and B.lr != A.lr
)
order by id               --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```