# Oracle SQL Create Corresponding Labels for Paired Right Left Sequential Numbers with Identifiers

Tags: oracle

I am trying to pair left right parts in a table. I [received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474749/oracle-sql-pair-right-left-sequential-numbers-with-identifiers) for a very similar question pairing left right parts but I now need to create a new column stating the corresponding paired part.

For example I have

```
ID  LR  Identifier
1   L   B15A
2   R   A15C
3   L   A15C
4   R   A15C
5   L   A15C
6   R   D5A2
9   R   D5A2
10  L   E5A6 
11  R   E5A6
12  L   E5A6
13  R   E5A6
14  R   H9S5
17  L   EE5A
18  R   EE5A
```

and I need the query to return

```
ID  LR  Identifier Counterhand Counterpart
2   R   A15C       L           3
3   L   A15C       R           2
4   R   A15C       L           5
5   L   A15C       R           4
10  L   E5A6       R           11
11  R   E5A6       L           10
12  L   E5A6       R           13
13  R   E5A6       L           12
17  L   EE5A       R           18
18  R   EE5A       L           17
```

The link to the previous question is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474749/oracle-sql-pair-right-left-sequential-numbers-with-identifiers). Very helpfully answered by @mathguy

Comment: Can we assume every paired ID is next to it's counterpart in ID Sequence?

Comment: @xQbert Yes they are in numeric order and each counterpart is either the preceding number or the following number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify @mathguys previous solution and check if each result is the first or second in a pair:

```
mod(row_number() over (partition by identifier order by id), 2)
```

will give you either 0 or 1; and then you can then choose to either lead or lag to get the previous or next hand/ID value:

```
case mod(row_number() over (partition by identifier order by id), 2)
  when 0 then lag(lr) over (partition by identifier order by id)
  else lead(lr) over (partition by identifier order by id) end as counterhand
```

Blatantly copying and extending [@mathguy's previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475111/266304):

```
with
     test_data ( id, lr, identifier ) as (
       select 001, 'L', 'B15A' from dual union all
       select 002, 'R', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select 003, 'L', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select 004, 'R', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select 005, 'L', 'A15C' from dual union all
       select 006, 'R', 'D5A2' from dual union all
       select 009, 'R', 'D5A2' from dual union all
       select 010, 'L', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select 011, 'R', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select 012, 'L', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select 013, 'R', 'E5A6' from dual union all
       select 014, 'R', 'H9S5' from dual union all
       select 017, 'L', 'EE5A' from dual union all
       select 018, 'R', 'EE5A' from dual
     )
-- end of test data, the solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select id, lr, identifier,
  case mod(row_number() over (partition by identifier order by id), 2)
    when 0 then lag(lr) over (partition by identifier order by id)
    else lead(lr) over (partition by identifier order by id) end as counterhand,
  case mod(row_number() over (partition by identifier order by id), 2)
    when 0 then lag(id) over (partition by identifier order by id)
    else lead(id) over (partition by identifier order by id) end as counterpart
from ( select id, lr, identifier,
              row_number() over (partition by identifier, lr order by id) as rn,
              least( count(case when lr = 'L' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier),
                     count(case when lr = 'R' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier)
                   ) as least_count
       from   test_data
)
where rn <= least_count
order by id               --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

gives you:

```
        ID L IDEN C COUNTERPART
---------- - ---- - -----------
         2 R A15C L           3
         3 L A15C R           2
         4 R A15C L           5
         5 L A15C R           4
        10 L E5A6 R          11
        11 R E5A6 L          10
        12 L E5A6 R          13
        13 R E5A6 L          12
        17 L EE5A R          18
        18 R EE5A L          17

10 rows selected.
```

The same two case statements can be added to the second version in @mathguy's previous answer, and gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing to build on prior answer... @mathguy did the hard work, and after reading Alex's answer I think his is more compact, i'm using a union that he's not, we both used ROw_number and mod.

```
with cte2(ID, LR, Identifier) as (
SELECT 1,'L','B15A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'R','A15C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'L','A15C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'R','A15C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'L','A15C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'R','D5A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'R','D5A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'L','E5A6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'R','E5A6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,'L','E5A6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13,'R','E5A6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14,'R','H9S5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17,'L','EE5A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18,'R','EE5A' FROM DUAL),
cte1 as (select id, lr, identifier
from ( select id, lr, identifier,
              row_number() over (partition by identifier, lr order by id) as rn,
              least( count(case when lr = 'L' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier),
                     count(case when lr = 'R' then 1 end) over (partition by identifier)
                   ) as least_count
       from   Cte2
)
where rn <= least_count
order by id),
cte as (Select A.*, Row_number() over (order by ID) RN from cte1 A)


SELECT A.Id
     , A.LR
     , A.Identifier
     , case when A.LR = 'R' then 'L' 
            when A.LR = 'L' then 'R' end as CounterHand
     , B.ID as CounterPart
FROM Cte A 
INNER JOIN cte B
 on A.RN+1 = B.RN
WHERE mod(A.RN,2)=1

UNION 

SELECT B.Id
     , B.LR
     , B.Identifier
     , case when B.LR = 'R' then 'L' 
            when B.LR = 'L' then 'R' end as CounterHand
     , A.ID as CounterPart
FROM cte A 
INNER JOIN cte B
 on A.RN = B.RN-1
WHERE mod(B.RN,2)=0
```